# ggplot2: issue with y-axis scaling in bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I wanne create a bar chart using the following code:

```
ggplot(data_set, aes(x=reorder(regionname, +gdpcap), y=gdpcap)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

As seen in the code, the y-axis doesn't simply display the count but the mean of the variable 'gdpcap' for each category on the x-axis.

In the dataset, the values for the variable 'gdpcap' are continuous and only range from 1 to 10.
But in the graphic output of my code, the values on the y-axis are multiplied by ten and display '0', '20', '40', '60' instead of just '0, 2, 4, 6'. It can be seen in the attached picture:
[bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LI98.png)

Why is ggplot scaling my y-axis differently?
If I would just calculate the mean, using the following code...

```
mean(data_set$gdpcap)
```

...then the output would be 3.681204 and not 30.681204.
So something in the ggplot command is causing the issue I assume. Any ideas?

Thanks for any help!

Thomas

Answer (score 0):

> As seen in the code, the y-axis doesn't simply display the count but the mean of the variable 'gdpcap' for each category on the x-axis.

No, that's not the case. Nothing in your code tells `ggplot` to take a mean. `stat = "identity"` means the y-values are taken as-is. The default `position = "stack"` means little bars for each observation are stacked on top of each other, so what you're seeing is the sum.

There's not a built-in way to plot means using `geom_bar`, but we can use `stat_summary` to have `ggplot` do the calculation. If it were me though, I'd use `dplyr` for the data transformation (that's what it's for) and `ggplot` for the plotting (that's what it's for).

Here it is both ways, demonstrated on the built-in `mtcars` data:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "col", fun = mean)


mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarize(mean_mpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  geom_col()
```

(I've switched to `geom_col`, which is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.)